# regex locate a place and replace the content found to another place located

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression which will find a place, gets its content and place it to another place on the same line.

I have done the bit where I can find the information that I want:

```
(?<=\{)(.*\n?)(?=\})
(?<=type=")(.*\n?)(?=" perm)
```

Example string:

```
<parameter name="some name" value="VALU" type="" perm="" ncpv="1"><doc></doc></parameter>  \type{INT}\ro some documentation
```

In this example, I want to place "INT" into "type=""" so it would become:

```
<parameter name="some name" value="VALU" type="INT" perm="" ncpv="1"><doc></doc></parameter>  \type{INT}\ro some documentation
```

So far I have the part which finds the place to put the information and the place that I want the information from but I am unsure how to move the information and combine the two regular expressions.

Comment: What tool are you using? And what regex flavor? Also, obligatory warning about using regular expressions to parse HTML: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Comment: @terdon I am trying to do that using my CLion IDE which supports regex.. but open to any tool like sed. I simply want to move the information to the appropriate place in an enormous xml file which is the same as this example line. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple example you show, you can do (I saved the example string in `file`):

```
$ sed -E 's|type=""(.*)(\\type\{([^}]+)\}.*)|type="\3"\1\2|' file 
<parameter name="some name" value="VALU" type="INT" perm="" ncpv="1"><doc></doc></parameter>  \type{INT}\ro some documentation
```

However, this is extremely fragile and very likely to fail. For example,it will fail if your line has more than one instance of `\type{`, it only changes lines where `type=` is empty (`type=""`), it will not deal with nested tags, or with cases where a tag is split over multiple lines.

As always, using a dedicated XML parser is the way to go, but this will work for the simple cases.